# What SQL drivers are available in Windows to connect and what's SqlClient driver on ConnString?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, data-access-layer, sqlclient

I need to understand which drivers are available in windows to connect to SQL Server?

My question comes up because I know ODBC and OLEDB are the drivers to connect to a SQL Server and they appear in a connection string (we specify them).

However, if I specify `System.Data.SqlClient`, where do I find that driver in my system? Which versions are available to use? Does it mean that I can use odbc, oledb or `SqlClient` drivers to connect to SQL Server?

Worth mentioning that I know we have the ADO.NET Coding side to develop ODBC, oledb, and `SqlClient` code so that the driver we use in the connection string understand it.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" 
         connectionString="data source=tcp:dbtestserver.database.windows.net;initial catalog=dbtest;Connection Timeout=5;Max Pool Size=5;user id=myuser;password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"   
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Any good explanation about drivers and most of all `SqlClient` driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Data.SqlClient is part of .NET Framework and is built-in to Windows. It's an ADO.NET provider and does not rely on either ODBC or OleDb.  Windows also ships with old OleDb and ODBC drivers.  And a newer [OleDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15) drivers are available to download and install.